# Add records in a table instead of list items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm adding rows in the format of list items. However I don't know how to iterate the rows in a table using Angular JS. Can any one help me in this issue?

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <span ng-model="user.firstname">{{user.firstname}}</span>
            <span ng-model="user.lastname">{{user.lastname}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Thank you in advance
Nizam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be somewhat like

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td> <span ng-model="user.firstname">{{user.firstname}}</span> </td>
        <td> <span ng-model="user.lastname">{{user.lastname}}</span> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Edwin.

Comment: Sure, I'll do Edwin. Where are you from by the way?